# Python list of string manipulation

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Consider the list ['010','10','00'] ; I'm trying to identify index positions that contain the character '1'. Here, the expected result is, [0,1], since element 1, '010' contains '1' at index 1 and element 2, '10' contains '1' at index 0.

```
sample = ['010','10','00']
result = set()
for e in sample:
   for i,c in enumerate(list(e)):
       if c == '1':
           result.add(i)
```

Is there a more efficient solution for this?

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me, but I'm not sure about using a `set()`?

Comment: `set()` is appropriate.  She doesn't care if `1` appears two, three, or ten times in a given position.

Comment: to get unique indices. even if list is ['010','01'], result should be just (1). Is there anyway we can use list comprehensions for achieving this?

Comment: @JohnGordon where was that ever implied in the question, other than the use of the set with no explanation?

Comment: What should the output be for `['010', '00',' 10']`? Or is that guaranteed to not happen?

Comment: @roganjosh The question says _I'm trying to identify index positions that contain the character '1'_  That's a boolean property; either a given index position contains '1', or it does not.  It's immaterial if it happens once, twice, or ten times.  Also, the code itself is behaving this way.  So that's two-for-two.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'll take that, as long as the OP is aware that sets don't maintain order. Considering how many questions around that are asked, I thought it best to check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `str.find()` method to more efficiently find the index of a substring within a string. And since `str.find()` returns `-1` when it fails to find the substring in a given string, you can remove `-1` from the resulting set afterwards:

```
print(set(s.find('1') for s in sample) - {-1})
```

This outputs:

```
{0, 1}
```

Edit: If you want to find all indexes of a substring in a string, you can use `re.finditer` instead, and union the resulting sets with `functools.reduce`:

```
import re
from functools import reduce
print(reduce(set.union, ({m.start() for m in re.finditer('1', s)} for s in sample)))
```

Comment: that's brilliant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: find() only returns the first occurrence, for instance '110'.find('1') will return only 0. I'm looking for a function that can return the result {0,1}

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with a solution that would return indexes of all occurrences of `'1'` in a string.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
sample = ['010','10','00']
result = set()
for i,e in enumerate(sample):
   if '1' in e:
       result.add(i)
```

Comment: Because that indexes the list and not the position of `1` in the string

Comment: I think she wants the positions of `1` within the individual items, not the positions of any item that contains `1`.  i.e. the first item is `010`, so that is a `1` in the second position.

Comment: Yea, im looking for the position of 1 within the individual list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer looks pretty good. Were you intending to get a set() or a list[]?

Assuming you meant to get a list, I changed your code a bit. 
check this out.

```
sample = ['010','10','00']
result = list()
for e in sample:
    for i,c in enumerate(list(e)):
        if c == '1':
            result.append(i)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, another try:

```
sample = ['010','10','00']
result = set()
for e in sample:
   i = e.find('1')
   if i != -1:
       result.add(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a commonly used method for dealing with python lists.

```
my_list = ['100','300','1001','000','000']
my_list = [x.find('1') for x in my_list if '1' in x]

print(my_list)
>> [0, 0]
```

**Edit:** Update code to get the index of 1 within the list element, instead of the index of the list element containing 1 within the list.

Comment: That doesn't work. The OP is trying to index characters within the strings inside the list, not list elements

Comment: You're absolutely right @roganjosh. I just updated the code to print the index of 1 within the list element.